# How to stop default timer in AngularJs - Timer plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I am try to stop **angular-timer functionality stop** as default but it's not working inside my controller i try this two method but both are not working.

```
$scope.timerRunning = false;

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
     $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
  });
```

// I try both but it's not working. Then hardly , i do changes inside the plugin.

```
if ($scope.autoStart === undefined || $scope.autoStart === true) {
          $scope.start();
        }
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/siddii/angular-timer/master/dist/angular-timer.js

I change this `$scope.start();` to `$scope.stop();`

If you have any other option then please share because i thing changes inside plugin is not good way.

Comment: How are you calling this method in te view?

Comment: Insert more code, it's not clear